# Overloaded signification on msdn

Tags: msdn, memorystream, overloading

I don't understand what does the overloaded term mean in the context of msdn library's page for MemoryStream Close method (or others like Dispose).

See the page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream_methods.aspx).
To me, overloaded points out the fact that you are providing a method with the same name but different signature than an existing one AND in the *same class*.

In this case, there's no existing Close method. Shouldn't it be override instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... it looks more like an MSDN glitch. From what I can see `MemoryStream` doesn't override, overload or re-declare (`new`) the `Close()` method. Not sure what MSDN is up to, to be honest.

I wonder if this distinction only exists for documentation purposes, because there **are** no unmanaged resources for a `MemoryStream` (and indeed the underlying buffer is still available).

> Closes the current stream and releases any resources (such as sockets and file handles) associated with the current stream.

vs

> Closes the stream for reading and writing.

it *does* override `Dispose(bool)`, though.